highcharts-export-server not producing svg when run from website
We have a website with php 8.1. It's supposed to use exec to run highcharts-export-server to generate an svg file, but the file does not get generated:
$cmd = '/var/www/mysite/node/node_modules/lib/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/bin/cli.js --infile /tmp/node_files/nso_2024-07-10__12.50.00_77003733f89002aca7337718298f07df.json --outfile /tmp/node_files/nso_2024-07-10__12.50.00_77003733f89002aca7337718298f07df.svg';
exec($cmd, $out, $retval);

**When I run this command directly on the command line it works perfectly and the svg is created. **
$retval output:
retval: [1]

This is the output from $out:
out: [Array
(
    [0] =>     __  ___       __         __               __
    [1] =>    / / / (_)___ _/ /_  _____/ /_  ____ ______/ /______
    [2] =>   / /_/ / / __ `/ __ \/ ___/ __ \/ __ `/ ___/ __/ ___/
    [3] =>  / __  / / /_/ / / / / /__/ / / / /_/ / /  / /_(__  )
    [4] => /_/ /_/_/\__, /_/ /_/\___/_/ /_/\__,_/_/   \__/____/
    [5] =>         ____//___/                  __     _____
    [6] =>        / ____/  ______  ____  _____/ /_   / ___/___  ______   _____  _____
    [7] =>       / __/ | |/_/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ __/   \__ \/ _ \/ ___/ | / / _ \/ ___/
    [8] =>      / /____>  </ /_/ / /_/ / /  / /_    ___/ /  __/ /   | |/ /  __/ /
    [9] =>     /_____/_/|_/ .___/\____/_/   \__/   /____/\___/_/    |___/\___/_/
    [10] =>               /_/
    [11] =>                                                                      v3.1.1
)
]

It doesn't go any farther than that. When I run it from the command line, I get:
    __  ___       __         __               __
   / / / (_)___ _/ /_  _____/ /_  ____ ______/ /______                    
  / /_/ / / __ `/ __ \/ ___/ __ \/ __ `/ ___/ __/ ___/                    
 / __  / / /_/ / / / / /__/ / / / /_/ / /  / /_(__  )                     
/_/ /_/_/\__, /_/ /_/\___/_/ /_/\__,_/_/   \__/____/                      
        ____//___/                  __     _____                          
       / ____/  ______  ____  _____/ /_   / ___/___  ______   _____  _____
      / __/ | |/_/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ __/   \__ \/ _ \/ ___/ | / / _ \/ ___/
     / /____>  </ /_/ / /_/ / /  / /_    ___/ /  __/ /   | |/ /  __/ /    
    /_____/_/|_/ .___/\____/_/   \__/   /____/\___/_/    |___/\___/_/     
              /_/                                                         
                                                                     v3.1.1
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:43 GMT-0400 [notice] - [cache] Dependency cache is up to date, proceeding.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:43 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [cache] writing new manifest
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:43 GMT-0400 [notice] - [browser] attempting to get a browser instance (try 0)
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:43 GMT-0400 [notice] - [pool] Initializing pool: min 1, max 1.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:43 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Attaching exit listeners to the process.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [notice] - [pool] Successfully created a worker e4cb0f2c-6d16-4afa-a54c-62f841a17a47 - took 229 ms.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [notice] - [pool] The pool is ready with 1 initial resources waiting.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [chart] Starting exporting process.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [chart] Attempting to export from an input file.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Work received, starting to process.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Acquiring worker
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [notice] - [browser] Could not clear page
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Releasing a worker of an id e4cb0f2c-6d16-4afa-a54c-62f841a17a47
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Acquired worker handle
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Starting work on pool entry e4cb0f2c-6d16-4afa-a54c-62f841a17a47.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [export] Determining export path.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [export] Treating as config.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Work completed in 134 ms.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [notice] - [pool] Killing all workers.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [notice] - [pool] Destroying pool entry e4cb0f2c-6d16-4afa-a54c-62f841a17a47.
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Destroyed a worker of an id e4cb0f2c-6d16-4afa-a54c-62f841a17a47
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [notice] - [browser] Could not clear page
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [verbose] - [pool] Releasing a worker of an id e4cb0f2c-6d16-4afa-a54c-62f841a17a47
Wed Jul 10 2024 12:46:44 GMT-0400 [notice] - [pool] Killing all workers.

I suspected it might be a permissions issue, and I changed everything in the node folder to use www-data for the user and group, but I still get the output above. There are no php (nginx) errors. Because I don't see any errors in the node output or on the php side, I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm also not sure what the retval of 1 indicates.


You should try out the current master branch (v4.0.0) which has solved many of the performance & health issues: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server. This can possibly solve the problem.

What you're reading with the $out is the contents of the console log, not the SVG. The log output is not full.

The $retval will most likely be the returning value of the Node (exporting) process where 0 means that the process ended without any kind of failure and 1 means that the process ended with some failure.

The $retval will not contain the SVG output, but the process exit code described above. Unfortunately, because the only log is the Highcharts logo, you will have to enable full logging (set the --logLevel 4 flag) and provide the full log before we know what exactly goes wrong in the exporting process.


The error that you get there should tell you exactly what went wrong during the exporting and investigate why this error does not happen for the command run in the terminal manually.
